# Errors that disk is full. df -k only shows 51%

Tags: amazon-ec2, disk-space-utilization

Amazon ec2, web server, no database.  I could not create a new file with touch, I couldn't even use tab completion because it complained about not being able to create a file.

Someone else just started rebooting it.  Is there something else I could have looked at to get a better insight?

When it was reporting full:

```
$ df -k
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       8115168 3845480   3834412  51% /
none                   4       0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             1922448      12   1922436   1% /dev
tmpfs             385484     340    385144   1% /run
none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1927408       0   1927408   0% /run/shm
none              102400       0    102400   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdb        4057280    8252   3839596   1% /mnt
```

After 1 reboot, df -k did not work, saying it couldn't read the table.

After 2 reboots and it was working again:

```
$ df -k
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       8115168 2423396   5256496  32% /
none                   4       0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             1922448      12   1922436   1% /dev
tmpfs             385484     340    385144   1% /run
none                5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1927408       0   1927408   0% /run/shm
none              102400       0    102400   0% /run/user
/dev/xvdb        4057280    8252   3839596   1% /mnt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df -i` is another critical thing to check. That will show filesystem inode usage.

Other than that, there is a possibility that there were filesystem errors and in response to those, the kernel re-mounted the filesystem as read-only. If this happened, you would see filesystem-related errors in the output of `dmesg`, and the output of `$ cat /proc/mounts` would indicate that the filesystem is mounted `ro` instead of `rw`.

As an aside, this:

> Someone else just started rebooting it.

...is concerning.

As a sysadmin, there should never be a situation where the anonymous "someone" reboots a server you're using and you don't know who that person is. You were in the middle of troubleshooting and had the rug pulled out from under you. I'd suggest getting a team chatroom or the like where you can put your heads together and coordinate your actions.

Comment: Yea, rebooting without figuring out the problem first is troublesome.  It was inside the development environment, so it was certainly allowed.  It just doesn't solve the problem if it recurs.